# Переход из канала к боту

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Всем привет, нужно чтобы в канале был пост с кнопкой, при нажатие которой перебрасывало к боту
Но проблема в другом, можно ли указать какое либо значение при перехода к боту
Например: пост(книга по саморазвитию, кнопкой) в боте много книг и как сделать так чтобы после нажатия на кнопку человека перебрасывало на бота, и отправлялась ему та или иная книга.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, можно. Это называется Deep linking.

Вы можете сделать ссылку на своего бота такого вида:

`https://t.me/<bot>?start=<argument>`

И когда пользователь перейдет к боту по этой ссылке и нажмет кнопку `Start` для начала общения с ботом, бот получит команду

`/start <argument>`

Подробнее вот тут: https://core.telegram.org/bots#deep-linking